# file_put_contents not working of used from command line?

Tags: php, shell

Here is the contents of a PHP file:

```
<? 
file_put_contents('test.txt', 'stuff');
echo 'complete';
?>
```

I call this `test.php`, it is located in `/mnt`. It has 777 permissions. Now I go into SSH, and execute: `sudo /usr/bin/php /mnt/test.php`. I receive the `complete` message at the bottom of my script. Now, I cd into `/mnt`. Text.txt is not there. What gives?

Answer (score 6):

proper code is this:

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/test.txt', 'stuff');
echo 'complete';
```

otherwise, php writes file in "current working directory", not where it is put

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a path, so you are putting `stuff` into `text.txt` in the current working directory. That will be the directory you `cd` to (or your default directory for a new shell) before running `sudo`, not the directory the PHP script is in.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to include the absolute path, like so:

```
file_put_contents('/mnt/test.txt', 'stuff');
```

Otherise, PHP will just write the file in the working directory (which is usually `/home/user`)